# Guzzle issue with Access Token

Tags: laravel, access-token, guzzle

I'm trying to access my API from laravel project using Guzzle.
**The API is fine when I access it using Postman**.
However, when I access it from Laravel, it takes some time, and just return an empty page.

I also test the guzzle library with other API, and it works also.

Below is my code.

```
    $url = 'http://myapi.me/api/get?param=123';
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxx',        
            ]
    ]);
```

Below is test to other API taht works.

```
    $url = 'http://httpbin.org/get';
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $url);
```

Below is dd() result from Laravel,

```
    GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#298 ▼
    -reasonPhrase: "OK"
    -statusCode: 200
    -headers: array:15 [▼
    "Date" => array:1 [▶]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▶]
    "Transfer-Encoding" => array:1 [▶]
    "Connection" => array:1 [▶]
    "Set-Cookie" => array:1 [▶]
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-RateLimit-Limit" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining" => array:1 [▶]
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => array:1 [▶]
    "CF-Cache-Status" => array:1 [▶]
    "cf-request-id" => array:1 [▶]
    "Report-To" => array:1 [▶]
    "NEL" => array:1 [▶]
    "Server" => array:1 [▶]
    "CF-RAY" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:15 [▼
   "date" => "Date"
   "content-type" => "Content-Type"
   "transfer-encoding" => "Transfer-Encoding"
   "connection" => "Connection"
   "set-cookie" => "Set-Cookie"
   "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
   "x-ratelimit-limit" => "X-RateLimit-Limit"
   "x-ratelimit-remaining" => "X-RateLimit-Remaining"
   "access-control-allow-origin" => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
   "cf-cache-status" => "CF-Cache-Status"
   "cf-request-id" => "cf-request-id"
   "report-to" => "Report-To"
   "nel" => "NEL"
   "server" => "Server"
   "cf-ray" => "CF-RAY"
  ]
 -protocol: "1.1"
 -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#296 ▼
 -stream: stream resource @9 ▶}
 -size: null
 -seekable: true
 -readable: true
 -writable: true
 -uri: "php://temp"
 -customMetadata: []
 }
}
```

Also, when I access my page (not api) using Postman, it returns,

```
Could not get response
Parse Error: Invalid character in chunk size
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: if you said the code is correct, then there's must be missing param in postman.. show how u use postman instead

Comment: ZeroOne, postman is OK when I access directly to API url. The problem is when I'm using Guzzle.
If you read my question, the Postman error that I mention is when I'm accessing my page url. The error also happen when I'm access the page using browser.

Comment: what are you getting if you use `$res->getBody()` & `$res->getStatusCode();`

Comment: bhucho, great! getBody returns the results. Thanks for pointing out. By the way, why is this happen?

Comment: what you dd is object, it will not return data obtained just headers & streams, but you need to call the method to get the body of the message, in HTTP Request body is written separately at the end.